# Silent Office 2010 install - Config.xml not allowing setup to run

Tags: xml, office-2010, silent-installer

I have my Config.xml file setup like this -

```
<!-- <Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" /> -->

<!-- <Logging Type="standard" Path="%temp%" Template="Microsoft Office Professional Plus Setup(*).txt" /> -->

<!-- <PIDKEY Value="VolumeLicenseKey" />    

<!-- <USERNAME Value="Customer" /> -->

<!-- <COMPANYNAME Value="MyCompany" /> -->

<!-- <INSTALLLOCATION Value="%programfiles%\Microsoft Office" /> -->

<!-- <OptionState Id="ACCESSFILES" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="Access_PIA" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessAddinPWFiles" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessBarcodeControl" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessBDCFiles" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessHelpFiles" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessLobiDependencies" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessWizards" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="DeveloperWizards" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <OptionState Id="AccessTemplatesIntl" State="Absent"/>

<!-- <LIS CACHEACTION="CacheOnly" /> -->

<!-- <DistributionPoint Location="\\server\share\Office" /> -->

<!-- <OptionState Id="OptionID" State="absent" Children="force" /> -->

<!-- <Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="Never" /> -->
```

I am trying to do a silent install without installing Access because the users have an application that isn't compatible with Access2010.  I have done some research in the TechNet and everything seems to be correct.  I can't get the C:\Office2010\setup.exe /config C:\Office2010\ProPlus.WW\config.xml command to run.  It says my config.xml file is not right and to check syntax or run setup.exe without the /config.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with my config.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't comment on your post as it requires 50 reputation but I thought it was worth mentioning that with Office 2010 instead of using an XML to specify the desired configuration you can use the packaged OCT (Office Customization Tool) utility to generate a MSP file which will be run on install.

After generating your MSP using OCT you can place the generated file into the Updates folder in the Office 2010 directory and it will be run automatically.

To read more here's an article on technet which will help.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490647.aspx

Comment: The only issue is that the MSP file is stored in a network location and the majority of people this needs to be deployed to are remote and our VPN is awful so deploying across that really isn't an option.  So the way I was going to do this was deploying with a modified Config.xml file.

Comment: The MSP file is stored in the Updates folder within the Office 2010 install directory, after setup.exe has installed Office the process looks inside the Updates folder and applies any MSP files it find. It should not be placed on a network share, please see the answer I provided to somebody experiencing problems putting the MSP on a network share: http://serverfault.com/questions/616910/silent-install-of-office-2013-with-mdt-2013/616967#616967.

Comment: Okay, tested it and it seems to work fine.  However it isn't a truly silent install.  It is about as close as you can get but it will work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

All of the lines in your config.xml are commented out (surrounded by `<!-- these -->`). This means that all of them will be ignored and the defaults used instead. For whichever of those lines you've changed from the default values, you need to remove the comment tags from around them in order for those lines to be applied.